# logback: Appender for logging to a website?

Tags: logging, spring-mvc, web, slf4j, logback

I'm using slf4j + Logback in a *Spring Web MVC* project. Besides logging to stdout using the "ConsoleAppender", I had the idea of seeing the same logs on a webpage (think of an admin area inside my *Spring Web MVC* project. Are there already such kind of *see-your-logs-as-HTML* implementations available for Logback?

On-demand generation of log website would be great, fallback to static HTML would also be okay.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess you have couple of options in regards to Logback. This is the same scenario I was battling with a while back.

- **DBAppender** to log to a db table (MySQL, Oracle etc) and write some **backend** code (**PHP/JAVA**) to fetch the tables. You can also look into **PHP template engines**(ex TinyButStrong) that provide pretty simple way to access databases to present the view (html) - http://logback.qos.ch/manual/appenders.html
- From my painful experience, I've convinced my team to use **Splunk** for Logging purposes. It's an amazing tool, and easy to setup without the overhead above. It provides a web interface for all your logging/monitoring purposes. So...you are not buildig it yourself. And they have **500mb** free license per day. Which isn't much, but its worth it. http://docs.splunk.com/Documentation/Splunk
  Installing Splunk - http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ogS4QEOrYW8

I suggest you give Splunk a try first.

Answer (score 2):

And just to augment the Splunk answer a bit , there are LogBack Appenders for sending events directly to Splunk : https://github.com/damiendallimore/SplunkJavaLogging